# Can Matplotlib's Basemap draw non-existing/fictive geography?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'd like to generate a fictive map using custom data, but still make it look like a map, just not this world. It should contain the earth-like ocean, terrain, and so on.

From Baseman's documentation, it never mentioned that it can be used for this purpose. All the examples show real-world maps.

Comment: Do you already have this data in some form or other (and want to convert it to another format in order to display it), or are you looking to ways of _create_ the data description itself?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding Basemap's role in the map-making process, to an extent:

Basemap is most useful for displaying Shapefiles, and other [primitives](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) in a Matplotlib figure, and [displaying data on the map](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html). What you're talking about (I think) is the generation of a fictional/imaginary base map. If that's the case, a tool like [QGIS](http://www2.qgis.org/en/site/) is far more suitable, and people [have certainly used it](http://ssrebelious.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/qgis-for-d-part-1-do-you-need-gis.html) for the creation of fantasy maps.